# How to define difference name for the same url pattern in django

Tags: django

```
url(r'^minigames/?$', views.MinigameViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'}), name="minigame_list"),
url(r'^minigames/?$', views.MinigameViewSet.as_view({'post': 'create'}), name="minigame_create"),
```

I want define url with the name like that, How can i do?

Comment: Hi ductx! Try to add some code to you post so other developers can help you

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using [Django REST Framework ViewSets](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/).  If you do it that way, then you'll need to `def list(self, request)` and `def create(self, request)` on the `MinigameViewSet` class as shown [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#example).

Comment: But what i want is define them with difference url name,  but i dont know how

Comment: It's fine if the url name is the same (though it could be different if you want it to be).  With using the same url name, the distinction then comes in the REST verbs that you are mapping to, which you appear to be doing correctly.  But if you want to have different names, that will work too.